# Determine whether browser supports javascript from within iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building an iframe that will go into my clients' web pages.  I need to figure out if the user's browser supports javascript and serve back the either the javascript or non-javascript version of the page accordingly.

What's the best way to determine javascript support in this case?  I thought about using javascript to rewrite the iframe url to include a GET variable indicating javascript support.  However, that would create two requests to the server, one for the initial load and then another once the javascript rewrites the URL.  Is there a way to only submit one request?  Or is there a better way to determine javascript support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't you opt for the <`noscript`> tag?

```
<script>
document.write('<iframe src="javascript_enabled_page.html"></iframe>');
</script>

<noscript>
<iframe src="javascript_disabled_page.html"></iframe>;
</noscript>
```

Comment: I like it.  Don't know why my mind was wrapped around a more complex solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't detect JavaScript support.  You should serve a page that works without JavaScript, and add JavaScript that alters the page in whatever way is appropriate for when JavaScript is available.

Comment: That is only the case when your service is actually possible without Javascript enabled, though.